# Is it possible to do this? (Involves destructuring and reassignment)

Tags: node.js, api, request, response, destructuring

```
const request = require('request');

const url = 'https://api.darksky.net/{secret_key}/37.8267,-122.4233';

request({ url }, (error, { body: data }) => {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data.currently);
});
```

This code snippet comes from an online course on NodeJS. I was messing around with the code (I didn't supply the secret API key) but I was curious to try and accomplish two lines of code into one statement, specifically I wanted to:

```
request({ url }, (error, { body: data }) => {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
```

-Destructure the response ( which I accomplished using {body: data})

-JSON.parse the data

I am curious to know if it is possible to do these two things in the parameters where the response is located (second parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegantly. Destructuring is only intended to extract properties of existing objects into variables, but not to do additional processing. It's *possible*, using a hack, by using a 3rd parameter (which the `request` doesn't provide), which gets defaulted to the `JSON.parse`d `data`:

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
request({ url }, (error, { body: data }, parsedData = JSON.parse(data)) => {
  console.log(parsedData);
});
```

But that's confusing, and shouldn't be done.

Another similar method, without a 3rd parameter, but using a non-existent property of the response object:

```
request({ url }, (error, { body: data, parsedData = JSON.parse(data) }) => {
  console.log(parsedData);
});
```

But these are just silly tricks. Parsing the JSON on the first line of the callback is definitely the *right* way to do this sort of thing.

Another option, which you might or might not find to be more elegant, is to use node-fetch. With it, you can call `.json()` on the Response object instead, indicating that the it should be parsed as JSON rather than as text (for plain text, you'd use `.text()`):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((obj) => {
        console.log(obj);
    });
```

Comment: Seems like my attempt of optimizing the code actually complicates the code more than it helps.  Definitely some good advice, thanks.